# Adding a border or separating line between each ListView item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, xamarin, android-custom-view

I am using Xamarin and have a ListView with a CustomAdapter for a Custom Row.

Here is the code for the CustomAdapter:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var item = items[position];
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapLocationDetail, null);
    view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TextViewMapHeading).Text = item.Heading;
    view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.TextViewDescription).Text = item.SubHeading;
    view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Image).SetImageResource(item.ImageResourceId);
    return view;
}
```

Here is the layout code for MapLocationDetail:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewMapHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="80 Chesterton Street"
            android:textColor="#ff000000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="This is a description"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:autoLink="all" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Image"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When the items are added to the ListView, there is no line or border between each item. How can I add a border to each item, or if not a border, a separating line between each item?

I have tried this with no result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#FFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about the color you are using, the background and divider are both white, so you can't see the divider, change the divider to another color.